# Custom allocator not correctly called in MSVC

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++

I was playing around with custom allocator, but there is nothing printed using `MSVC` *(Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.26.28805 for x86)*, while there is in *GCC / Clang*.
The comment part needs to be uncommented when using GCC/Clang, but it will stop MSVC to compile, and I don't know if I am doing anything wrong here.

I found the issue [here](https://github.com/nlohmann/json/issues/1472), but it seems the issue is still not resolved in [GCC10](https://godbolt.org/z/W3ZLWj)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
struct MyAllocator :std::allocator<T>
{

    auto allocate(size_t size)
    {
        std::cout << "Allocating: "<<size<< " elements\n";
        return new T[size];
    }

    void deallocate(T* ptr, size_t size)
    {
        std::cout << "Free: "<<size<<" elements\n";
        delete[] ptr;
    }

    /*uncomment the following for GCC or clang*/
    /*template <typename U>
    struct rebind
    {
        using other = MyAllocator<U>;
    };*/
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int, MyAllocator<int>> v{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    std::vector<size_t, MyAllocator<size_t>> v2{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    std::cin.get();
}
```

EDIT: With all the compilers, I am using C++17 standard

Comment: That's part of the reason why you don't inherit from `std::allocator` but rather implement necessary [`std::allocator_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits) functionality and adhere to named requirements of an [_Allocator_](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator)

Comment: Just in case, there is a [minimalistic allocator example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator#Examples) on the cppreference page mentioned above.

Comment: Your example [compiles for me](https://godbolt.org/z/oTLsqq) with MCSV and `rebind` uncommented.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik It doesn't compile if you try in Visual studio. Also it may be because the version in Compiler Explorer is 19.24, instead of 19.26